# /bin/ls --color=always fails to produce colorized output in shell-mode

Tags: shell, colors, shell-mode

I *have* run `M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on`.

Also, when I use `/bin/ls --color=always` (or `/bin/ls --color=auto`) in a regular terminal, I do see colors in the output.

It's only within Emacs' `shell-mode` that these commands fail to produced colorized output.  (The variable `LS_COLORS` is set to the empty string in all cases.)

Strangely enough, `grep --color=always` does produce colorized output, even in `shell-mode`.  The *echoed* commands are are also colorized.

[image: screenshot]

(NB: in the illustration above I passed the options `-1aF --color=always` to `/bin/ls`, but I get the same "monochrome" output with no flags, or with any combination of flags, and with any argument for the `--color` option.)

***Is there anything else I need to do to get `/bin/ls` to produce colorized output in `shell-mode`?***

---

**config**

```
;; ~/.emacs

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
(require 'comint)
(set-face-attribute 'comint-highlight-prompt nil
                    :inherit nil)
```

```
# ~/.zshrc
LS_COLORS='';
export LS_COLORS

PS1=$'%# '
```

Comment: The doc string for `ansi-color-for-comint-mode` says, "In order for this to have any effect, `ansi-color-process-output` must
be in `comint-output-filter-functions`". Is it, for you? (It is, for me -- I have `(ansi-color-process-output comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom comint-watch-for-password-prompt)` -- and I get `ls` colors.)

Comment: Hmm maybe that's N/A, because it's already showing colors for you -- just not for `ls`.

Comment: @GregHendershott: Thanks for your comment.  I just checked, and my settings for that variable are identical to yours.

Comment: Emacs 25.0.50.1 here and `ls` produces colored output when run in `shell-mode`, what version are you using?

Comment: @wvxvw: GNU Emacs 24.4.1

Comment: My Emacs (GNU Emacs 24.5.1) sets `TERM=dumb` in `startup.el` and my `ls` from GNU coreutils 8.24 checks `TERM` even with `--color=always`. `dumb` is not a terminal type recognized by `dircolors` (the utility used by `ls` to decide how to color the output), so running `TERM=ansi ls --color=always` in a `*shell*` buffer works as expected, while `ls --color=always` does not. So, I would recommend creating an alias similar to `alias lls="TERM=ansi gls --color=always"`.

Comment: @Constantine: that's great!  Thank you!  Please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Emacs (GNU Emacs 24.5.1) sets `TERM=dumb` in `startup.el` and my `ls` from GNU coreutils 8.24 checks `TERM` even with `--color=always`. `dumb` is not a terminal type recognized by `dircolors` (the utility used by `ls` to decide how to color the output), so running `TERM=ansi ls --color=always` in a `*shell*` buffer works as expected, while `ls --color=always` does not.

So, I would recommend creating an alias similar to

```
alias ls="TERM=ansi ls --color=always"
```